# remove the sub categories list from the category product listing page

Tags: magento-1.8

I have done the product listing customization. But when click the category link, i got an subcategories listing page with product listing. I dont want to display the subcategories list when category has the products list.

example I have those category here.http://testbase.info/c/collectivecraft/WebSite/index.php/collections.html

Now when click on any category, you can see the category's product listing page with the sub category list. I do not want display the subcategory here.

How can it possible ? please help.

Answer (score 1):

Magento does not have the subcategory listing shown by default.
Actually this is a feature that a lot of people requested and you have it but don't want it.
Most probably you have the display mode set to 'Static block' for some categories.
If this is the case, then edit the category and change the display mode to 'Product only'.